# some issues with a c# jumping code in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

This the code I am having issues with, in fact when I press the space button, the player will just repeat the animation of jump and even the right arrow doesn't work anymore.

Please if you could help you will be more than welcome

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public float Speed = 30f;
    public float JumpForce = 30f;
    bool Jump;
    float speed;
    private bool  FacingRight;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
            FacingRight = true;
            rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Jump", true);        
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {        
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("speed", 1);
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.right * Speed * Time.deltaTime;                    
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("speed", 1);
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.left * Speed * Time.deltaTime;                   
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("speed", 0f);
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;                  
        }

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Flip(horizontal);
    }

    private void Flip (float horizontal)
    {
        if (horizontal > 0 && !FacingRight || horizontal < 0 && FacingRight)
        {
            FacingRight = !FacingRight;
            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            theScale.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }
    }

     void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name ==" Front_Buildings")
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("isGrounded", true);
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero ;      
        }              
    }       
}
```

Comment: Guess you're missing a "GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Jump", false);"

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set your jump back to false

`GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Jump", false);`

Also you have an `else` when the left arrow is (not) pressed. So your right arrow (which is not left) will set the speed and velocity to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set the animator Jump attribute to 'true' here.

`GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Jump", true);`

Do you ever set this back to false? You only want it to be true once, in order to begin the animation, then it should be set back to false so that the animation does not just repeat endlessly.